# Executables made by cx_Freeze cannot run when distributed to other computers with error "entry point ucrtbase._set_fmode could not be located"

Tags: python, executable, cx-freeze

I built executable using cx_Freeze with python3.6. It works fine on the computer where the executable is built. But when distributed to other computers which have the exactly same windows OS, the executable crashes down with an error message "The procedure entry point ucrtbase._set_fmode could not be located in the dynamic link library api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll.

This is seemingly due to version mismatch of api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll between the one on the OS and the one required by the executable. I noticed cx_Freeze actually bundled this dll file when creating the executable, but how to let it used by default?